# Same footer on pages

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

In the WE below, I was attempting to get the same footer on each page of the document (except the first page of the chapter), however, I get the footer appearing only on the odd pages.  Can you help me get the same footer on both the odd and even pages?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{plain}

% auxiliary counter
\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

% the list of colors to be used (add more if needed)
\newcommand\BoxColor{%
  \ifcase\thechapshift blue!30\or red!30\or olive!30\or magenta!30\else yellow!30\fi}


% redefinition of \chaptermark to contain only the title
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.~#1}{}}

%======================================================================================
%   PAGE HEADERS
%======================================================================================

\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \ #1}{}} % Chapter text font settings
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}} % Section text font settings
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage} % Font setting for the page number in the header
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north east]
  at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{black}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}} % Print the nearest section name on the left side of odd pages
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north west]
  at ($ (current page.north west) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{black}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}} % Print the current chapter name on the right side of even pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt} % Width of the rule under the header
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt} % Increase the spacing around the header slightly
\newcommand{\footrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.5pt}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{%
\cfoot[\fancyplain{}{}] {\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\bfseries{Center Foot}}} \lfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]
{\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape{Left Foot}}}
\rfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]
{\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape{Right Foot}}}
}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{%
\cfoot[\fancyplain{}{}] {\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\bfseries{Center Foot}}} \lfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]
{\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape{Left Foot}}}
\rfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]
{\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape{Right Foot}}}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} % Style for when a plain pagestyle is specified

% Removes the header from odd empty pages at the end of chapters
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\vskip 40\p@}
  {\vskip 40\p@\stepcounter{chapshift}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Width of the rule under the header
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot[\fancyplain{}{}] {\fancyplain{}{}} \lfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]
{\fancyplain{}{}}
\rfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]
{\fancyplain{}{}}
{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} % Style for when a plain pagestyle is specified
}

\part{Part One}
\mainmatter
\chapter[Intro]{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-7]
\section{This is how we do it}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Results}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Some Sample Code}
\lipsum[1-7]

\part{Part Two}
\appendix
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \appendixname~\thechapter}{}}
\chapter{This is Appendix A}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{This is Appendix B}
\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The use of `\fancyplain` is deprecated. A quick look at the `.sty` file suggests that it did not work properly and caused problems. It is included only for compatibility reasons (i.e. compiling old documents).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clean up your [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) definitions.

For redefining the `plain` page style to only have a page number in the top-right, use

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Width of rule under header
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Width of rule above footer
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}}
```

For defining the `fancy` page style *footer* you might be interested in

```
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.5pt}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape Left foot}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\bfseries Center foot}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape Right foot}
```

Here is your example code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% auxiliary counter
\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

% the list of colors to be used (add more if needed)
\newcommand\BoxColor{%
  \ifcase\thechapshift blue!30\or red!30\or olive!30\or magenta!30\else yellow!30\fi}


% redefinition of \chaptermark to contain only the title
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.~#1}{}}

%======================================================================================
%   PAGE HEADERS
%======================================================================================

\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \ #1}{}} % Chapter text font settings
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}} % Section text font settings
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage} % Font setting for the page number in the header
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
      text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north east]
    at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
    {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
      \centering\textcolor{black}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}} % Print the nearest section name on the left side of odd pages
  \fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
      text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north west]
    at ($ (current page.north west) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
    {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
      \centering\textcolor{black}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}} % Print the current chapter name on the right side of even pages

\newcommand{\footrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt} % Width of the rule under the header
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt} % Increase the spacing around the header slightly
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.5pt}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape Left foot}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\bfseries Center foot}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape Right foot}

% Removes the header from odd empty pages at the end of chapters
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{%
  \clearpage
  \ifodd\value{page}\else
    \mbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
  \fi}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\vskip 40\p@}
  {\vskip 40\p@\stepcounter{chapshift}}{}{}
\makeatother

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Width of rule under header
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Width of rule above footer
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}}


\begin{document}

\part{Part One}
\mainmatter
\chapter[Intro]{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-7]
\section{This is how we do it}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Results}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Some Sample Code}
\lipsum[1-7]

\part{Part Two}
\appendix
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \appendixname~\thechapter}{}}
\chapter{This is Appendix A}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{This is Appendix B}
\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```